# ERROR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname knode: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have already got the **ssh key** but when I am trying to copy the `ssh` key to my node I am getting error in copying that key.

I have already tried to do that in root user and also tried many other methods but none of it worked.

I have tried the command:

```
sudo-copy-id -i knode
```

Using this command the key must have been copied to my node.

But I am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/moglix/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname knode: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

host name knode is not resolving, use fully qualified domain name or check why host name is not resolving. 
You can are an entry in /etc/host file for "knode" with ip as workaround